# REGEXP_EXTRACT String Start with AG or TS, and capture everything after

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, looker

Below is the dataset examples, each row has the following values:

| row | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AG3608-sueyfbnd-sjwfk |
| 2 | TS2649-sjwjmdaqo-wkdmfl |
| 3 | wudjeolssopp |
| 4 | sjhwu78iwjm |

so on....

I want to extract values that start with either AG or TS, and capture everything after. Below is the desired outcome

| row | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AG3608-sueyfbnd-sjwfk |
| 2 | TS2649-sjwjmdaqo-wkdmfl |

I wrote something like this, but it's only capturing the the first 2 letters AG or TS
`regexp_extract(${column},'^(AG|TS).*')` it doesn't capture everything after

Comment: Why not use `STARTS_WITH(column, 'AG') OR STARTS_WITH(column, 'TS')`?

Answer (score 1):

Use both a capturing and non-capturing groups:

```sql
regexp_extract(${column},'^((?:AG|TS).*)')
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      AG                       'AG'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      TS                       'TS'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  regexp_extract(value, r'^(?:AG|TS)(.*)') as everything_after
from data
where regexp_contains(value,'^(AG|TS)')
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]